# A Tab that become visible if an action button condition is met in R shiny not updating the rendered Data table

Tags: r, shiny, tabs, hidden

I am trying to create a ShinyApp with two tabs ( a "Home" tab and a "Info" tab, the second of which is hidden tab hat only gets activated or visible once the action button "Display Data" is clicked), and a sidebar that has got a dropdown menu. It is meant to just show a constant " Hello and Welcome" message in the home tab, and depending on the user option, display the data in the "Info" tab when and if action button is clicked (otherwise it won't display the second "Info" tab and just show the "Home" tab).

Now the problem is that the first time I run the app, it's working as desired and displaying the relevant rendered data table in the "Info" tab based on the user selection from the drop down menu and mainly clicking the "Display Data" button afterwards. However, if the user then selects another option from the drop down menu and clicks the "Display Data" action button, it's not updating or changing the rendered data table in the "Info" tab accordingly. That is basically what I need help with (being able to show updated rendered table every time user selects another option from the drop down menu), as I am new to Shiny and recently started learning it. Any help will be much appreciated and thanks in advance.

Here is the code I have so far for creating the data frame from which the table is rendered and the shiny global.R, ui.R and server.R code.

```
# global.R

cities <- data.frame("Continent" =
    c('Europe','Europe', 'Europe', 'America', 'America', 'Africa', 'Africa', 'Asia', 'Asia'), 
  "City" = c('Berlin','London','Madrid','Washington DC', 'Los Angeles', 'Cairo', 'Pretoria', 'Shanghai', 'Dubai'),
  "Population"= c(3620340,8821025,3223000,700000,3973000,9540000,2473000,26000000,3331000))

selection_function <- function(continent_choice) {
  if (!continent_choice == "All"){
    data <- cities[cities$Continent==continent_choice, ]
  } else {
    data <- cities
  }
  return (data)
}


# ui.R

library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel(h1("My App")),
  
  # Sidebar
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(inputId = "id1", 
                  label = HTML("Please select a continent"),
                  choices = c("All", sort(unique(cities$Continent)))
      ),
      tags$br(), tags$br(),
      actionButton("action1", "Display Data"),
      tags$br(), tags$br()
    ),

    # Main Panel
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(id="the_id",
                  tabPanel("Home", br(),
                           h3("Hello and welcome, this is my App"),
                           tags$br(), tags$br(),
                           h5("Navigate through the options on the left")
                  )
      )
      
      
    )
  ))
)

server.R

library(shiny)
library(DT)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  
  
  observeEvent(input$action1,{
    the_continent <- selection_function(input$id1)
    appendTab(inputId = "the_id", 
              tabPanel("Info", br(),
                       DT::renderDataTable({
                         the_continent
                       }) ))
    
  }, once = TRUE )
  
})
```

Finally, I would also like to ask if there are any other better ways of trying to do what I am doing (like maybe doing this with conditionalPanel as opposed to the append tab option that I am doing)? I am saying so, because I think it's much better to handle things in the client side instead of the server side. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Edit

We can use `dataTableProxy` to create a proxy table and replace the data only when the button is pressed. This way we also prevent loosing the "state" of the table when new changes happen.

App:

```
# global.R

library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(DT)


cities <- data.frame(
  "Continent" =
    c("Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "America", "America", "Africa", "Africa", "Asia", "Asia"),
  "City" = c("Berlin", "London", "Madrid", "Washington DC", "Los Angeles", "Cairo", "Pretoria", "Shanghai", "Dubai"),
  "Population" = c(3620340, 8821025, 3223000, 700000, 3973000, 9540000, 2473000, 26000000, 3331000)
)

selection_function <- function(continent_choice) {
  if (!continent_choice == "All") {
    data <- cities[cities$Continent == continent_choice, ]
  } else {
    data <- cities
  }
  return(data)
}


# ui.R

ui <- fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel(h1("My App")),
  useShinyjs(),

  # Sidebar
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(
        inputId = "id1",
        label = HTML("Please select a continent"),
        choices = c("All", sort(unique(cities$Continent)))
      ),
      tags$br(), tags$br(),
      actionButton("action1", "Display Data"),
      tags$br(), tags$br()
    ),

    # Main Panel
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        id = "the_id",
        tabPanel(
          "Home", br(),
          h3("Hello and welcome, this is my App"),
          tags$br(), tags$br(),
          h5("Navigate through the options on the left")
        )
      )
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  table <- reactive({
    the_continent <- selection_function(input$id1)
  })

  observeEvent(input$action1,
    {
      the_continent <- selection_function(input$id1)
      appendTab(
        inputId = "the_id",
        tabPanel(
          "Info", br(),
          DT::DTOutput("dt_table")
        )
      )

      output$dt_table <- DT::renderDT({
        isolate(table())
      })
      updateTabsetPanel(
        session  = session,
        inputId  = "the_id",
        selected = "Info"
      )
    },
    once = TRUE
  )

  proxy <- dataTableProxy("dt_table")

  observeEvent(input$action1, {
    replaceData(
      proxy          = proxy,
      data           = table(),
      resetPaging    = FALSE,
      clearSelection = FALSE
    )
  })
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Another way to do it is to call `DT::renderDT` inside the observeEvent but outside the `apendTab` function. The downside is that the datatable will be reset every time the button is pressed.

```
# global.R

library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)


cities <- data.frame(
  "Continent" =
    c("Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "America", "America", "Africa", "Africa", "Asia", "Asia"),
  "City" = c("Berlin", "London", "Madrid", "Washington DC", "Los Angeles", "Cairo", "Pretoria", "Shanghai", "Dubai"),
  "Population" = c(3620340, 8821025, 3223000, 700000, 3973000, 9540000, 2473000, 26000000, 3331000)
)

selection_function <- function(continent_choice) {
  if (!continent_choice == "All") {
    data <- cities[cities$Continent == continent_choice, ]
  } else {
    data <- cities
  }
  return(data)
}


# ui.R

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel(h1("My App")),
  useShinyjs(),
  
  # Sidebar
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(
        inputId = "id1",
        label = HTML("Please select a continent"),
        choices = c("All", sort(unique(cities$Continent)))
      ),
      tags$br(), tags$br(),
      actionButton("action1", "Display Data"),
      tags$br(), tags$br()
    ),
    
    # Main Panel
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        id = "the_id",
        tabPanel(
          "Home", br(),
          h3("Hello and welcome, this is my App"),
          tags$br(), tags$br(),
          h5("Navigate through the options on the left")
        )
      )
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  table <- reactive({
    the_continent <- selection_function(input$id1)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$action1,
               {
                 the_continent <- selection_function(input$id1)
                 appendTab(
                   inputId = "the_id",
                   tabPanel(
                     "Info", br(),
                     DT::DTOutput("dt_table")
                   )
                 )
                 
                 output$dt_table <- DT::renderDT({
                   input$action1
                   isolate(table())
                 })
               },
               once = TRUE
  )
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer but your new answer code is now resulting the updating or rendering of the new table before the user pressing the "Display Data" action button when they just change an option from the drop down menu in the side bar. How do I make sure sure that new data table is not rendered before pressing the action button?

Comment: @TheCuriousOne It is fixed now, i posted two different ways to achieve the same result. The first approach relies on `replaceData` function from DT, and the second approach is just isolating the data passed to the renderDT function and calling `input$action1` inside to force re calculation every time the button is pressed.

Comment: That's great, thanks. It is working as desired now. I will mark your answer as accepted but before that just want to ask if you can look into my second question written towards the end in the last paragraph of my question, and that is if there is a another way of doing this using conditionalPanel or not. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Using a function like `conditionalPanel` works to hide the contents of the tab, but not the tab itself. to alter the tabs we need functions like `insertTab` `prependTab` etc. I am only talking from an R perspective, maybe using javascript directly it is possible but unfortunately I don't know how to do it.

Comment: thanks, that makes sense. Finally can I ask you to explain to me what these lines mean in your solution using the second approach:

  output$dt_table <- DT::renderDT({
                   input$action1
                   isolate(table())
                 })

I mean I don't understand what  " input$action1 " is doing there and what "isolate(table())" means. Sorry to bother you , and thanks.

Comment: `input$action1` is there to ensure re calculation every time the button is pressed. The `isolate` function is there to prevent re evaluation when the contents of table() changes.

Comment: Very clear, thanks once more @jpdugo17